# Why am I unable to smelt my frying pan in TF2?

Tags: team-fortress-2

I can't smelt my frying pan with another sniper class weapon. The pan doesn't display in the crafting window, but it displays in my backpack.

Comment: Does it say "Not craftable" or something to that effect in your inventory? I'm almost certain the pan isn't craftable.

Comment: No. It just says unique I'm afraid :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because the Frying Pan is unobtainable by normal crafting methods and it isn't a drop in-game (only received by purchasing L4D2)

You need to craft "sniper-specific" weapons to be able to receive a scrap.  This means weapons ONLY equippable by the sniper, not by any other class. It is the same logic that prevents other reskinned multi-class Melees from being smelted.

Comment: Thanks loads:) Does this mean I'd need a sniper rifle (i.e The Classic) and something that can't be used by other classes?

Comment: @Clarinetking Yes.  So if you have another sniper weapon, like any sniper rifle, or any of his melees, or secondaries, you should be fine.

Comment: **This is not true!** You are able to melt multi-cass weapons like the Onscientious Objector.